# iOS app to track happiness

Tags: ios, iphone-app

I'm looking for an iOS app to track my happiness level throughout the day.

I would like the app to ask me to rate my current happiness level at multiple random or predefined times during the day. It would then be great to see graphs of my happiness level, as well as its average, over different time periods.

Being free and having an Apple Watch version as well would be a plus.

Comment: Lol, this is a neat idea I wouldn't have thought of.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy Thanks. I've found some apps that do this, but not with all the features described above. I want this because I'm pretty bad at gauging how happy I've been over time. I've read that most people are actually very inaccurate at this but are able to tell you how happy they are in any given moment.

Comment: I must say that's a good idea!

Answer (score 1):

I heard about a study that was being done on this very topic and it turns out they made an app for it!

I'm not quite sure if it has the ability to graph your happiness, but according to its description:

> Using this app, you’ll be able to track your happiness and find out what factors — for you personally — are associated with greater happiness.
>
> ...
>
> **A few times a day, you’ll get a notification** and be asked some questions about your experience at that moment. The idea is that by measuring your experience at many individual moments, **you’ll get an accurate picture of your life and the determinants of your happiness**.

Link to "Track Your Happiness" by Matt Killingsworth [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/track-your-happiness/id867266105?ls=1&mt=8).

Comment: Thank you. This is very interesting. I tried a similar study like this before, but this app looks a lot nicer. I would ideally like something similar though that just asks me how happy I am at multiple daily intervals, as well as let's me add a data point anytime I want. I'll try this out though.